# Create PayPal Dev Account to use sandbox without entering any banking credentials

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

As the title states, I wan't to use the PayPal Sandbox to test transactions in a given project. Now I wan't to create a Developer account and use it without entering any banking credentials.

I have been following the register guide until the 'add credentials'. Is there a way to ignore this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on PayPal developer documentation regarding [credentials](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_credentials), you can use test credentials, but it has to be assigned to one of your sandbox Business accounts. You could create a sandbox accounts by following the steps in this [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_create-accounts)